# border-color's transparent property

Tags: css

I've found this cool example of `border-color`'s `transparent` property usage to make an arrow.
I understand how borders are drawn and how an empty element with one side set border can help achieve arrow effect, but what makes me wander in this example is usage of transparent.
Take a look at this simple code:

```
<div id="daniel"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#daniel{
 border-color: rgba(111,111,111,0.2) transparent transparent;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 15px;
 position: absolute;
}
```

With this code I get an arrow pointing down. ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hDpnw/4/))

With only one transparent I get an `hourglass` effect. ([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hDpnw/5/)):

```
border-color: rgba(111,111,111,0.2) transparent;
```

What confuses me is not knowing what `border-{side}` `transparent` refers to in this shorthand properties.

Hope that makes sense.
Any help appreciated.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

there is a simple rule for the order in which the sides appear in such shorthand notations:

> TRouBLe: Top Right Bottom Left

if you have less than 4 arguments, the missing ones are filled with the following rules (depending on how many arguments are present or missing):

```
3 values present: left = right
2 values present: left = right & bottom = top
1 value present:  left = right = bottom = top
```

so in your example

```css
border-color: rgba(111,111,111,0.2) transparent transparent;
```

according to the rules, we have

```css
top = rgba
right = transparent
bottom = transparent
left = right = transparent
```

similar in the other example:

```css
border-color: rgba(111,111,111,0.2) transparent;
```

we get the following

```css
top = rgba 
right = transparent
bottom = top = rgba
left = right = transparent
```

Comment: I get it know, obvious. I thought that `rgba` refers to all  sides and then with transparent afterwards you pick ones you wish _not to be there_. Thanks man, thanks everyone!

Comment: This is a great answer, but if I am getting it right, the inferring order for the missing ones are: `right = top`, then `bottom = top`, then `left = right`. The order matters I guess, so maybe should edit the answer to re-order the lines in the first code snippet. BTW, the order in other snippets are in correct order though.

Comment: @EricWang The list was thought from end to start. So, if the last element is missing `left = right`, if the second to last is also missing `bottom = top`, etc. I'm not sure, if another ordering makes this clearer.

Comment: @Sirko What I mean is before you can do `left = right`, should first check `right = top`, because if `right` is missing, that's the first thing to do. So, maybe just re-order the `left = right
bottom = top
right = top` part to `right = top bottom = top left = right`

Answer (score 2):

What you need to know is `border-color:red black blue;` will make the top border red, the bottom one blue and the left and right ones black, and that explains why you get an arrow in your first example:

- Top colored
- everything else transparent

It also explains the 2nd example:

- Top & bottom colored
- left & right transparent

Example

```
This style rule assigns a red border to the top, a green border to the bottom, and blue borders to the left- and right-hand sides of paragraphs within the element with ID "example":
#example p {
  border-color: red blue green;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

[Source](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/border-color)

For a details explanation of the CSS triangle effect, see: [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Answer (score 0):

That refers to the Border style. Look at the specifications from  [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-border-color)

Answer (score 0):

Your

**first example**

```
border-color: rgba(111,111,111,0.2) transparent transparent;
```

Define

```
 first rgba border= is a top border;
 second transparent border = are left & right border;
 third  transparent border= are bottom border;
```

check this example http://jsfiddle.net/hDpnw/8/

&

your

**second example**

```
border-color: rgba(111,111,111,0.2) transparent;
```

Define

```
 rgba border= are top & bottom border;
 transparent border = are left & right border;
```

check this example http://jsfiddle.net/hDpnw/7/